# Is usher at the theatre a backstage worker?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

Choose the correct word or phrase:

> Jeremy got a job working __ at the theatre - he’s an usher and shows people to their seats.
> a) on stage    
> b) in the spotlight    
> c) front of house    
> d) backstage

Usher isn't on stage isn't in the spotlight and isn't backstage. So, the correct answer is c? I don't think so

Comment: This seems more like a theater-specific question than an English-language question.   Why do you think c) is wrong?  Did you look up "front of house"?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_of_house  I don['t see any reason to doubt this, and you have already eliminiated the impossilbe so whatever remains....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. ["Front of house" is defined as:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/front-of-house)

> the part of a business such as a restaurant or hotel where the employees deal directly with customers

Or:

> the employees of a restaurant, hotel, etc. who deal directly with customers

So an usher certainly qualifies.